# I have a problem with setting-up a server side callback with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, callback

I'm new to AJAX and PHP, I made an HTML file where I send info to a PHP file.

If I use a form submit then there is no problem, the php answer is fine.
When i tried to use AJAX instead of the form... i got stuck with the CrossDomain calls problem!

So I decided to use the JSON callback function and dynamic script tag solution. I've used it several times before, but just on the client side, Now I need to set-up the server side so my PHP file can answer back to the callback function. Here is the code for the explanation:

Html/Javascript file:

```
function setUrl(numeroAPI)
{
    var url = "http://localhost/Generatore/generatore_codice.php?numeroAPI=" + numeroAPI;       
    for(var i=1;i<=numeroAPI;i++)
    {
        url = url + "&tipoChiamataAPI" + i + "=" + document.getElementById("tipoChiamataAPI" + i).value;
    }
    url = url + "&callback=callback";
    creareScript(url);
}

function creareScript(url)
{
    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.src= url;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

function callback(obj)
{
    alert("lala");
}
```

Exactly this code has worked a lot of time in other programs.... but now the alert is not working, I have read that my PHP file should be something like this:

```php
$json = json_encode($data);

echo $_GET['callback'] . "(".$json.");";
```

So that's what I made... and of course I'm missing something... any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome XSS and other garbage

Comment: what does your url look like once you pass it to creareScript() ?

Comment: it depends... for example it could be

"http://localhost/Generatore/generatore_codice.php?numeroAPI=2&tipoChiamataAPI1=operazioneAPI1&tipoChiamataAPI2=eventoAPI2&callback=callback"

Answer (score 0):

you aren't even calling callback() function anywhere, so it can't work.

Additionaly, your code is dangerous.

try adding

```
callback();
```

after

```
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I dont need to call it! thats the fun bout the script tag! it should be AUTOMATICALLY called when i receive the answer from the server, i've  used before LOT of times so dont say it needs to be called! anyways the problem is not the javascript... but the php file...

Comment: the obj parameter in the callback function... is the json object sended by the server.... so i should use it for example alert(obj.data) or something like that... i used a simple alert("lala") just to see if the function was being called or not...

Comment: i solved the problem! the code IS CORRECT, the problem were 2 extra rows of code inserted by mistake! thanks to all!